# How to change gridline color

Tags: matlab, colors, properties, grid, styles

In current version of matlab 2017, gridline properties commands of earlier version are not working.
How to reset gridline color (major and minor).
How to change line weight and line style

```
set(gca,'GridLineColor',[0.7 0.2 0.1])
```

Comment: If you read [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#d119e56454) you'll see that it's `'GridColor'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
set(gca,'GridColor',[0.7 0.2 0.1])
```

Comment: I have tried this option also, but not working. I think problem lies in Default setting. How ti override it?

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: Windows 8.1 Operating System

Comment: I don't know how applicable this is for you but you can try changing opengl preferences. see here : https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html